# FormView with EntityDataSource, setting Where property causes error

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have this simple code,

```
Protected Sub grdSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grdSearch.SelectedIndexChanged
    TimeOff.Where = "UserName=""" & grdSearch.SelectedValue & """"
End Sub
```

Doing so causes this error,

> 'UserName' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make
>   sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas
>   are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple
>   identifier, line 6, column 1.

The datasource works fine before the where property is set. The error doesn't make any sense to me. What does it mean? What am I doing wrong?

Update: I found the issue but I still don't get it.

Adding `it.` in the where clause solves the issue. Like this,

```
TimeOff.Where = "it.UserName=""" & grdSearch.SelectedValue & """"
```

But other than the fact that the `it.` shows up in a few code examples, I can't find any explanation of what it means, what it stands for, or why its needed. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Adding it. in the where clause solves the issue. Like this,

TimeOff.Where = "it.UserName=""" & grdSearch.SelectedValue & """"